# Hibernate session filter with binary UUID/binary param fails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to apply a filter to a query of a table that contains a binary(16) represenation of a UUID, however I receive the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect filter parameter [accountId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.FilterImpl.setParameter(FilterImpl.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

I've tried these two filter declarations

```
@FilterDef(name="accountFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="accountId", type="binary" ) )
@Filter(name="accountFilter", condition=":accountId = account_id")
```

and

```
@FilterDef(name="accountFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="accountId", type="binary" ) )
@Filter(name="accountFilter", condition="UUID_TO_BIN(:accountId) = account_id")
```

Envoking the filter with the UUIDs `toString` method:

```
enableFilter(ACCOUNT_FILTER, "accountId", currentUser.getAccount().getId().toString());
```

Both result in the same error.

Using MySQL 8.0.23 and Hibernate 5.4.32. The column is defined as a binary(16) data

Answer (score 0):

I had the WHERE clause UUID function flip flopped. It should look like this:

```
@FilterDef(name="accountFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="accountId", type="string" ) )
@Filter(name="accountFilter", condition=":accountId = UUID_TO_BIN(account_id)")
```

With a String being passed as the filters param.